# Possible to send an email if a Jenkins 'Build Passes' after a Build Failure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Possible to send an email if a Jenkins 'Build Passes' after a Build Failure?

1. For example I have x3 builds that fail
2. But the fourth build passes

Is it then possible to send email to say that the build has passed

Comment: If you are sending build status for every build, it should do the job. Or are you looking something else?

Comment: @skjoshi thanks for the comment, im looking to only send an email if the last build failed but the current build passed, is it even possible?

Comment: My suggestion here would be to use email-ext plugin with a custom script. You might want to write a small custom script based build step to decide to send the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using shell script in Jenkins.

## Get current build status

`CURRENT_BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}api/json | jq -r '.result')`

## Get previous build number

`prevBuildNo=$(($BUILD_NUMBER-1))`

`echo $prevBuildNo`

## Get previous build status

`PREVIOUS_BUILD_STATUS=$(curl -- silent http://jenkins.org.com/jenkins/job/job/jobname/${prevBuildNo}/api/json | jq -r '.result)`

## Cheking if the previous build was failed and the current build is successful

`if ["$CURRENT_BUILD_STATUS" = "SUCCESS"] && ["$PREVIOUS_BUILD_STATUS" = "FAILED"]
then
  #sending the mail
  echo $ echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" someone@somewhere.com
else
  echo "No e-mail trigger as the previous build was successful."
fi`